# Data not sent to External Accessory in iOS7.1

Tags: bluetooth, usb, communication, ios7.1, external-accessory

We have an iPad application which communicates with External Accessory connected to ipad via USB/Bluetooth. While communicating to external accessory, application opens stream and starts pushing data and recieving data. In iOS 7.1 and iOS 7.1.1 we are facing issue where after initial connection and disconnection, when application reconnects to External Accessory it successfully detects, connects and open communication stream but after few data exchange the communication dies out. After debugging and carefull observation we have found that the response is coming from external accessory, but the  though the data is sent sucessfully from application never reaches external accessory.

What might be cause and resolution of this issue.

Thank you for the help and input.

Answer (score 0):

Apple just released new update 7.1.2 claiming they have resolved this type of issues.

"• Fixes a bug with data transfer for some 3rd party accessories, including bar code scanners"*